# Jest Vue failing: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs, quasar, snapshot-testing

I have sucessfully setup Jest with Quasar and Vue and most of my tests work. The only test that is failing is this one because of the following error message

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

/Users/kristijanstefanoski/Desktop/Projektt/Quasar/projektt/node_modules/capacitor-firebase-auth/dist/esm/index.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){export * from './definitions';
                                                                                         ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

> 1 | import * as auth from 'capacitor-firebase-auth';
    | ^
  2 | import * as firebase from "firebase";
  3 | import store from '../store';
  4 | import {set} from "src/mixins/storage";

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:537:17)
  at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:579:25)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/mixins/auth.js:1:1)
```

I have already added the following in my jest config:

```
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!quasar/lang)',
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!capacitor-firebase-auth/)',
  ],
```

I also tried the following

```
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!quasar/lang)',
    '<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!capacitor-firebase-auth/dist/esm/)',
  ],
```

But again without luck. Anything I might be missing?

Comment: I don't think the problem is with firebase itself. This happens often with Jest and babel when you're importing files such as `.css`. Can you show the test file?

Comment: @Tony It is just plain Snapshot test file, just importing the component and running the test against it

Comment: Yes and if that component imports files that aren't included in the `moduleFileExtensions`. Jest will not be able to handle them as stated in the error log >`This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.`. Which is why I need to check your test file and component file. If that is the case you'll need to stub/mock those files